# comparing averages of different sized groups

Tags: mean

I want to look at the number of arrests per head of population in some counties. What I am doing is taking the census for each period and using 10 year periods (so dividing by 10).

For 1810-19 I divide by 10 and compare with the 1811 census; 
for 1820-29 I divide by 10 and compare with the 1821 census,

The problem I have is that the data only begin in 1805 so for 1805-9 I have 6 years to compare with the 1801 census.

Is this OK?

---

OK, sorry for being vague, I want to look at the number of persons indicted per head of population per year. So, i am taking the number dividing it by the population given in the census for that decade, times 100,000 and then divide by 10. This is ok for the actual decades (for 1810-19 I am using the 1811 census and for 1820-29 I am using the 1821 census). The problem is for the period 1805-1809. If i do the above but divide by 5 for the 5 years, can i still compare the 3 periods?

Comment: Why not just interpolate the populations smartly?

Comment: hi - that sounds a bit more complex than i need. I dont think i am explaining myself very well :-(

Comment: Assuming implicitly that the population changed in big steps is likely to prove much more awkward and inaccurate.

Comment: OK - im just looking at broad trends though. shall i try and explain again - i dont think im expressing it as best as i can :-(

Comment: If your basic idea is to relate **totals** over differing numbers of years, then clearly the number of years you use should be adjusted for. Is that what you are asking? Put it this way: how do you compare the total height of 5 men and the total height of 10 men?

Comment: OK, and again apologies that I am not explaining this very well: 

* i want to make a broad statement about the changes in the average annual number of indictments per 100,000 of the population over the period 1805-1830. I am going to do this by relating it to the size of the population in the county (so, number of indictments / population x 100,000 / 10)

* For the period 1810-1819, Im using the 1811 census so dividing by 10 for the annual average. Similarly for the 1820-29 period, im using the 1821 census.

Comment: * the problem is 1805-9, which is only 5 years. The average here would be /5 and not 10, so im guessing not comparable, right? If so is there any easy way to do this? Again, i just want to make broad statements about each decade block

Comment: I don't see how this raises new points that can be answered. Why not comparable?  Why you are taking averages any way? Decades strike me as utterly arbitrary units.

Comment: Decades made sense in terms of the census. Im taking averages because that is what other people doing similar research have done. So are you saying its ok to compare the decades with the 5 year period?

Comment: Just because the census took place every 10 years from 1801 has no bearing on whether decades (any set of decades) are a good way to summarize crime statistically.  I would focus on say annual crime totals and average in 10 year blocks if and only if the crime seemed to jump once per decade. Above all, relating years ending in 9 to the census totals 8 years before is a highly inaccurate idea. If you are a historian or student of history, I think you need to talk at some length with someone knowing more statistics at your university or other workplace.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would help to know the hypothesis you are testing. I find it a bit odd that you are counting e.g the number of arrests in 1819 to the census of 1811, yet 1819 is only 2 before the next census (and 8 years after the 1811 census).

If you are just testing whether the proportion of arrested people changed over time you might just plot both the number or arrested people and total inhabitants in the same graph with x being years. Then you can see if they have the same trend. If e.g. both increase linearly you might just check if they differ in their slope. (I think an ANCOVA might work, if residuals are normally distributed and variances are equal).

I might be wrong, though!

Comment: @John: I do not have enough reputation to comment your post, therefore I comment mine. I think you should follow Nick Cox suggestion and interpolate the population more smartly. I think what that means is you should first model the population and get estimates for each year e.g. if they increase linearly you can just make a linear regression and based on the estimates you get, you can estimate the population of each year.

Comment: Hi - that sounds a bit more complex than i need. I don't think i am explaining myself very well here :-/

Comment: If you want to do something really simple, then just look at the proportion of arrested people in the years where a census took place. Then you do not need to interpolate anything.

Comment: thanks - but i also want to look at executions, which did not always take place in census years